# Como puedo obtener los campos de un formulario con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Un placer saludarlos de nuevo, en esta ocasión me surge la duda de como puedo obtener los valores de un formulario con múltiples tipos de inputs (text, date, etc), el formulario también posee campos de tipo select, necesito obtener esos valores para posteriormente enviarlos a otro lugar

Al ser un formulario muy extenso esta divido en secciones:

```
<div class="form-page active">
            <h2>Página 1</h2>
            <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

            <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
            <input type="email" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

            <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

            <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

            <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

            <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
            <input type="text" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">

            <label for="">lorem ipsum</label>
            <input type="date" name="" id="" class="form-input" placeholder="Algo random">
 </div>
<div class="form-page">
                <h2>Página 2</h2>
                <label for="nombre-cuenta">Cuenta</label>
                <input type="text" name="cuenta" id="nombre-cuenta" class="form-input" placeholder="Ingrese la cuenta">

                <label for="select-cuenta">Tipo de cuenta</label> <br>
                <select name="tipo-cuenta" id="select-cuenta">
                    <option value="default" selected>Seleccione una opción</option>
                    <option value="baja">Baja</option>
                    <option value="alta">Alta</option>
                </select>                                                          
 <div/>
```

Espero me puedan ayudar a saber como obtener estos valores, de antemano muchas gracias y saludos.

Comment: La propiedad value te proporciona el valor del input. Por otra parte para enviar los valores del formulario debes agregar un input de tipo submit. Eso hara el envio del formulario donde indiques. Si quieres manejar el envio con javascript debes usar la funcion preventdefault y ahi si puedes manejar los value de cada input. Mdn tiene una buena explicacion de manejo de formularios, incluso en castellano. Tambien puedes visitar la web de jonmircha o su pagina en youtube, tiene muy buenos tutoriales

Comment: Vale muchas gracias, veré eso que me recomendaste, saludos.